# Панели инструментов создаются в отдельных окнах

Tags: python, tkinter

Даже не знаю что и делать эта кнопка должна быть на окне где находиться таблица.
Код программы:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class Main(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        super().__init__(root)
        self.init_main()

    def init_main(self):
        toolbar = tk.Frame(bg="#d7d8e0", bd=10)
        toolbar.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X)

        self.add_img1 = tk.PhotoImage(file = "siren_emergency_lights_hooter_police_icon_191334.png")
        btn_open_dialog1 = tk.Button(toolbar, text="Заявка", command=lambda:self.open_dialog1(), bg="#d7d8e0", bd=0,
                                      compound=tk.LEFT, image = self.add_img1)
        btn_open_dialog1.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

        self.add_img = tk.PhotoImage(file="icons8-администратор-microsoft-50.png")
        btn_open_dialog2 = tk.Button(toolbar, text="ЗаявкаГАИ", command=lambda:self.open_dialog2(), bg="#d7d8e0", bd=0,
                                     compound=tk.LEFT, image=self.add_img)
        btn_open_dialog2.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

        self.add_img2 = tk.PhotoImage(file="icons8-администратор-microsoft-50.png")
        btn_open_dialog3 = tk.Button(toolbar, text="Администратор", command=lambda: self.open_dialog3(), bg="#d7d8e0",
                                     bd=0, compound=tk.LEFT, image=self.add_img2)
        btn_open_dialog3.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

    def open_dialog2(self):
        ZaiavkaGAI()

    def open_dialog1(self):
        Zaiavka()

    def open_dialog3(self):
        Admin()

class Sotrudniki(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(root)
        self.init_Sotrudniki()

    def init_Sotrudniki(self):
        self.title("Сотрудники")
        self.geometry("600x420+400+300")
        self.resizable(False, False)

        self.grab_set()
        self.focus_set()

        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self, columns=("ID", "FIO driver", "nomber ud", "nomber pass", "age jods", ), height=15,
                                 show="headings")
        self.tree.column("ID", width=20, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column("FIO driver", width=150, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column("nomber ud", width=150, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column("nomber pass", width=120, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column("age jods", width=170, anchor=tk.CENTER)

        self.tree.heading("ID", text = "ID")
        self.tree.heading("FIO driver", text="ФИО водителя эвак.")
        self.tree.heading("nomber ud", text="Номер удостоверения")
        self.tree.heading("nomber pass", text="Номер паспорта")
        self.tree.heading("age jods", text="Трудовой стаж")
        self.tree.pack()

class ZaiavkiADM(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self):
         super().__init__(root)
         self.init_ZaiavkiADM()

    def init_ZaiavkiADM(self):
        self.title("Заявления на эвакуацию")
        self.geometry("797x420+400+300")
        self.resizable(False, False)

        self.grab_set()
        self.focus_set()

        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self, columns=("ID", "FIO driver", "nomber ud", "nomber pass", "nomber car","Data",
                                                "Vid"),
                                 height=15,show="headings")
        self.tree.column("ID", width=25, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column("FIO driver", width=120, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column("nomber ud", width=120, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column("nomber pass", width=120, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column("nomber car", width=120, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column("Data", width=150, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column("Vid", width=180, anchor=tk.CENTER)

        self.tree.heading("ID", text="ID")
        self.tree.heading("FIO driver", text="ФИО водителя")
        self.tree.heading("nomber ud", text="Номер удостоверения")
        self.tree.heading("nomber pass", text="Номер паспорта")
        self.tree.heading("nomber car", text="Номер машины")
        self.tree.heading("Data", text="Дата подачи заявления")
        self.tree.heading("Vid", text="Вид заявления")
        self.tree.pack()


class Protocol(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.init_Protocol()

    def open_dialog7(self):
        Dobavlenie_Protocol()

    def init_Protocol(self):
        self.title("Протокол")
        self.geometry("900x420+400+300")
        self.resizable(True, True)

        '''self.entry_description = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.entry_description.place(x=400, y=50)''' "Добавление записи"

        self.grab_set()
        self.focus_set()
        toolbar2 = tk.Toplevel(bg='#d8d9e9', bd=0)
        toolbar2.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X)
        self.add_img6 = tk.PhotoImage(file="siren_emergency_lights_hooter_police_icon_191334.png")
        btn_open_dialog7 = tk.Button(toolbar2, text="Заполнить протокол эвакуации", command=lambda: self.open_dialog7(),
                                     bg="#d7d8e0", bd=0,
                                     compound=tk.LEFT, image=self.add_img6)
        btn_open_dialog7.pack(side=tk.TOP)
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self, columns =("ID", "nomber car arrest", "FIO driver", "nomber car","adress arest",
                                                 "adres stop", "Data arrest"), height = 15,
                                 show="headings")
        self.tree.column("ID", width=20, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column("nomber car arrest", width=150, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column("FIO driver", width=150, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column("nomber car", width=120, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column("adress arest", width=170, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column("adres stop", width=170, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column("Data arrest", width=150, anchor=tk.CENTER)

        self.tree.heading("ID", text = "ID")
        self.tree.heading("nomber car arrest", text="Номер эвак. машины")
        self.tree.heading("FIO driver", text="ФИО водителя")
        self.tree.heading("nomber car", text="Номер эвакуатора")
        self.tree.heading("adress arest", text="Место эвакуации")
        self.tree.heading("adres stop", text="Место доставки")
        self.tree.heading("Data arrest", text="Дата эвакуации")
        self.tree.pack()




class ZaiavkaGAI(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(root)
        self.init_ZaiavkaGAI()

    def init_ZaiavkaGAI(self):
        self.title("Заполнить заявку ГАИ")
        self.geometry("400x320+400+300")
        self.resizable(False, False)

        label1 = tk.Label(self,text="Сотрудник ГАИ", fg="#eee", bg="#333")
        label1.pack()


        self.entry_description = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.entry_description.place(x=180, y=30)

        self.entry_description = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.entry_description.place(x=180, y=60)

        self.entry_description = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.entry_description.place(x=180, y=90)

        self.entry_description = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.entry_description.place(x=180, y=120)

        self.entry_description = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.entry_description.place(x=180, y=150)

        self.entry_description = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.entry_description.place(x=180, y=180)

        self.grab_set()
        self.focus_set()



class Admin(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self):
        self.init_Admin()
        super().__inits__()

    def open_dialog4(self):
        Protocol()

    def open_dialog5(self):
        Sotrudniki()

    def open_dialog6(self):
        ZaiavkiADM()


    def init_Admin(self):
        toolbar1 = tk.Toplevel(bg='#d8d9e9', bd=0)
        toolbar1.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X)
        self.add_img3 = tk.PhotoImage(file="siren_emergency_lights_hooter_police_icon_191334.png")
        btn_open_dialog4 = tk.Button(toolbar1, text="Протокол эвакуации", command=lambda: self.open_dialog4(), bg="#d7d8e0", bd=0,
                                     compound=tk.LEFT, image=self.add_img3)
        btn_open_dialog4.pack(side=tk.TOP)
        self.add_img4 = tk.PhotoImage(file="siren_emergency_lights_hooter_police_icon_191334.png")
        btn_open_dialog5 = tk.Button(toolbar1, text="Сотрудники", command=lambda: self.open_dialog5(), bg="#d7d8e0", bd=0,
                                     compound=tk.LEFT, image=self.add_img3)
        btn_open_dialog5.pack(side=tk.TOP)

        self.add_img5 = tk.PhotoImage(file="siren_emergency_lights_hooter_police_icon_191334.png")
        btn_open_dialog6 = tk.Button(toolbar1, text="Заявления на эвакуацию", command=lambda: self.open_dialog6(),
                                     bg="#d7d8e0", bd=0,
                                     compound=tk.LEFT, image=self.add_img3)
        btn_open_dialog6.pack(side=tk.TOP)

class Zaiavka(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.init_Zaiavka()

    def init_Zaiavka(self):
        self.title("Заполнить заявку")
        self.geometry("400x320+400+300")
        self.resizable(False, False)
        label1 = tk.Label(self,text="Частное лицо", fg="#eee", bg="#333")
        label1.pack()

        self.entry_FIO_driver = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.entry_FIO_driver.place(x=180, y=30)

        self.entry_ud = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.entry_ud.place(x=180, y=60)

        self.entry_pass = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.entry_pass.place(x=180, y=90)

        self.entry_nomder_car = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.entry_nomder_car.place(x=180, y=120)

        self.entry_Data = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.entry_Data.place(x=180, y=150)

        self.grab_set()
        self.focus_set()

class Dobavlenie_Protocol(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.init_Dobavlenie_Protocol()

    def init_Dobavlenie_Protocol(self):
        self.title("Заполнить протокол")
        self.geometry("400x320+400+300")
        self.resizable(False, False)

        self.entry_nomber_car_driver = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.entry_nomber_car_driver.place(x=180, y=30)

        self.entry_FIO = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.entry_FIO.place(x=180, y=60)

        self.entry_nomber_car_arrest = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.entry_nomber_car_arrest.place(x=180, y=90)

        self.entry_adress_arest = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.entry_adress_arest.place(x=180, y=120)

        self.entry_jail_adress = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.entry_jail_adress.place(x=180, y=150)

        self.entry_Data = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.entry_Data.place(x=180, y=180)

        self.grab_set()
        self.focus_set()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Main(root)
    app.pack()
    root.title("Эвакуаторное агенство")
    root.geometry("450x250+100+200")
    root.resizable(False, False)
    root.mainloop()
    pass
```

Как получить данную ошибку.

1. При запуске программы нажать кнопку администратор
2. Нажать кнопку протокол эвакуации.

[image: Скрин проблемы]

Comment: поменять `__inits__` на `__init__` ?

Comment: При этой замене происходит следующее: Создается еще одно лишнее окно. 1. нажать на кнопку администратор(и оно появляеться,если исправить как было на inits, то лишнее окно не создаеться)

Comment: Рекомендую попробовать запустить этот код у себя и выястнить причину,так как я уже ломаю голову второй день

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы зачем-то создаёте тулбары наследуясь от `Toplevel` (отсюда и "лишние" окна). В `Main` же сделали правильно - от `Frame`.
Чтобы эти `Frame` встали в нужное окно, надо передать им `self` первым параметром.
Ну и `__init__()` у предков вызывать в первую очередь.
Да, и "лечение" собственных ошибок намеренным созданием ошибок в коде (это я о `__inits__()`) - это какой-то новый подход. Ни разу с таким не встречался. :)

*(извините, но картинки из кода повыкинул, ибо вы их не приложили, вернёте сами)*

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class Main(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        super().__init__(root)
        self.init_main()

    def init_main(self):
        toolbar = tk.Frame(self, bg="#d7d8e0", bd=10)
        toolbar.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X)

        self.add_img1 = tk.PhotoImage(file = "siren_emergency_lights_hooter_police_icon_191334.png")
        btn_open_dialog1 = tk.Button(toolbar, text="Заявка", command=lambda:self.open_dialog1(), bg="#d7d8e0", bd=0,
                                      compound=tk.LEFT)
        btn_open_dialog1.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

        self.add_img = tk.PhotoImage(file="icons8-администратор-microsoft-50.png")
        btn_open_dialog2 = tk.Button(toolbar, text="ЗаявкаГАИ", command=lambda:self.open_dialog2(), bg="#d7d8e0", bd=0,
                                     compound=tk.LEFT)
        btn_open_dialog2.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

        self.add_img2 = tk.PhotoImage(file="icons8-администратор-microsoft-50.png")
        btn_open_dialog3 = tk.Button(toolbar, text="Администратор", command=lambda: self.open_dialog3(), bg="#d7d8e0",
                                     bd=0, compound=tk.LEFT)
        btn_open_dialog3.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

    def open_dialog2(self):
        ZaiavkaGAI()

    def open_dialog1(self):
        Zaiavka()

    def open_dialog3(self):
        Admin()

class Sotrudniki(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(root)
        self.init_Sotrudniki()

    def init_Sotrudniki(self):
        self.title("Сотрудники")
        self.geometry("600x420+400+300")
        self.resizable(False, False)

        self.grab_set()
        self.focus_set()

        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self, columns=("ID", "FIO driver", "nomber ud", "nomber pass", "age jods", ), height=15,
                                 show="headings")
        self.tree.column("ID", width=20, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column("FIO driver", width=150, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column("nomber ud", width=150, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column("nomber pass", width=120, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column("age jods", width=170, anchor=tk.CENTER)

        self.tree.heading("ID", text = "ID")
        self.tree.heading("FIO driver", text="ФИО водителя эвак.")
        self.tree.heading("nomber ud", text="Номер удостоверения")
        self.tree.heading("nomber pass", text="Номер паспорта")
        self.tree.heading("age jods", text="Трудовой стаж")
        self.tree.pack()

class ZaiavkiADM(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self):
         super().__init__(root)
         self.init_ZaiavkiADM()

    def init_ZaiavkiADM(self):
        self.title("Заявления на эвакуацию")
        self.geometry("797x420+400+300")
        self.resizable(False, False)

        self.grab_set()
        self.focus_set()

        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self, columns=("ID", "FIO driver", "nomber ud", "nomber pass", "nomber car","Data",
                                                "Vid"),
                                 height=15,show="headings")
        self.tree.column("ID", width=25, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column("FIO driver", width=120, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column("nomber ud", width=120, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column("nomber pass", width=120, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column("nomber car", width=120, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column("Data", width=150, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column("Vid", width=180, anchor=tk.CENTER)

        self.tree.heading("ID", text="ID")
        self.tree.heading("FIO driver", text="ФИО водителя")
        self.tree.heading("nomber ud", text="Номер удостоверения")
        self.tree.heading("nomber pass", text="Номер паспорта")
        self.tree.heading("nomber car", text="Номер машины")
        self.tree.heading("Data", text="Дата подачи заявления")
        self.tree.heading("Vid", text="Вид заявления")
        self.tree.pack()


class Protocol(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.init_Protocol()

    def open_dialog7(self):
        Dobavlenie_Protocol()

    def init_Protocol(self):
        self.title("Протокол")
        self.geometry("900x420+400+300")
        self.resizable(True, True)

        '''self.entry_description = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.entry_description.place(x=400, y=50)''' "Добавление записи"

        self.grab_set()
        self.focus_set()
        toolbar2 = tk.Frame(self, bg='#d8d9e9', bd=0)
        toolbar2.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X)
        self.add_img6 = tk.PhotoImage(file="siren_emergency_lights_hooter_police_icon_191334.png")
        btn_open_dialog7 = tk.Button(toolbar2, text="Заполнить протокол эвакуации", command=lambda: self.open_dialog7(),
                                     bg="#d7d8e0", bd=0,
                                     compound=tk.LEFT)
        btn_open_dialog7.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self, columns =("ID", "nomber car arrest", "FIO driver", "nomber car","adress arest",
                                                 "adres stop", "Data arrest"), height = 15,
                                 show="headings")
        self.tree.column("ID", width=20, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column("nomber car arrest", width=150, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column("FIO driver", width=150, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column("nomber car", width=120, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column("adress arest", width=170, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column("adres stop", width=170, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column("Data arrest", width=150, anchor=tk.CENTER)

        self.tree.heading("ID", text = "ID")
        self.tree.heading("nomber car arrest", text="Номер эвак. машины")
        self.tree.heading("FIO driver", text="ФИО водителя")
        self.tree.heading("nomber car", text="Номер эвакуатора")
        self.tree.heading("adress arest", text="Место эвакуации")
        self.tree.heading("adres stop", text="Место доставки")
        self.tree.heading("Data arrest", text="Дата эвакуации")
        self.tree.pack()




class ZaiavkaGAI(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(root)
        self.init_ZaiavkaGAI()

    def init_ZaiavkaGAI(self):
        self.title("Заполнить заявку ГАИ")
        self.geometry("400x320+400+300")
        self.resizable(False, False)

        label1 = tk.Label(self,text="Сотрудник ГАИ", fg="#eee", bg="#333")
        label1.pack()


        self.entry_description = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.entry_description.place(x=180, y=30)

        self.entry_description = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.entry_description.place(x=180, y=60)

        self.entry_description = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.entry_description.place(x=180, y=90)

        self.entry_description = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.entry_description.place(x=180, y=120)

        self.entry_description = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.entry_description.place(x=180, y=150)

        self.entry_description = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.entry_description.place(x=180, y=180)

        self.grab_set()
        self.focus_set()



class Admin(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.init_Admin()

    def open_dialog4(self):
        Protocol()

    def open_dialog5(self):
        Sotrudniki()

    def open_dialog6(self):
        ZaiavkiADM()


    def init_Admin(self):
        toolbar1 = tk.Frame(self, bg='#d8d9e9', bd=0)
        toolbar1.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X)
        self.add_img3 = tk.PhotoImage(file="siren_emergency_lights_hooter_police_icon_191334.png")
        btn_open_dialog4 = tk.Button(toolbar1, text="Протокол эвакуации", command=lambda: self.open_dialog4(), bg="#d7d8e0", bd=0,
                                     compound=tk.LEFT)
        btn_open_dialog4.pack(side=tk.TOP)
        self.add_img4 = tk.PhotoImage(file="siren_emergency_lights_hooter_police_icon_191334.png")
        btn_open_dialog5 = tk.Button(toolbar1, text="Сотрудники", command=lambda: self.open_dialog5(), bg="#d7d8e0", bd=0,
                                     compound=tk.LEFT)
        btn_open_dialog5.pack(side=tk.TOP)

        self.add_img5 = tk.PhotoImage(file="siren_emergency_lights_hooter_police_icon_191334.png")
        btn_open_dialog6 = tk.Button(toolbar1, text="Заявления на эвакуацию", command=lambda: self.open_dialog6(),
                                     bg="#d7d8e0", bd=0,
                                     compound=tk.LEFT)
        btn_open_dialog6.pack(side=tk.TOP)

class Zaiavka(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.init_Zaiavka()

    def init_Zaiavka(self):
        self.title("Заполнить заявку")
        self.geometry("400x320+400+300")
        self.resizable(False, False)
        label1 = tk.Label(self,text="Частное лицо", fg="#eee", bg="#333")
        label1.pack()

        self.entry_FIO_driver = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.entry_FIO_driver.place(x=180, y=30)

        self.entry_ud = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.entry_ud.place(x=180, y=60)

        self.entry_pass = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.entry_pass.place(x=180, y=90)

        self.entry_nomder_car = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.entry_nomder_car.place(x=180, y=120)

        self.entry_Data = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.entry_Data.place(x=180, y=150)

        self.grab_set()
        self.focus_set()

class Dobavlenie_Protocol(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.init_Dobavlenie_Protocol()

    def init_Dobavlenie_Protocol(self):
        self.title("Заполнить протокол")
        self.geometry("400x320+400+300")
        self.resizable(False, False)

        self.entry_nomber_car_driver = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.entry_nomber_car_driver.place(x=180, y=30)

        self.entry_FIO = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.entry_FIO.place(x=180, y=60)

        self.entry_nomber_car_arrest = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.entry_nomber_car_arrest.place(x=180, y=90)

        self.entry_adress_arest = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.entry_adress_arest.place(x=180, y=120)

        self.entry_jail_adress = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.entry_jail_adress.place(x=180, y=150)

        self.entry_Data = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.entry_Data.place(x=180, y=180)

        self.grab_set()
        self.focus_set()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Main(root)
    app.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X)
    root.title("Эвакуаторное агенство")
    root.geometry("450x250+100+200")
    root.resizable(False, False)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Благодорю за помощь,по скольку это мой первый серьезный проект в программировании,буду еще писать сюда и задавать вопросы)

Comment: @ДанилаМарковский [как принято говорить "спасибо" на SO (StackOverflow) ;)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/348814)